# Calculating worst case asymptotic running time for multi-function algorithm

Tags: java, runtime, complexity-theory

```
int coffee(int n) {
    int s = n * n;
    for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)
        s = s - q;
    for (int q = n; q > 0; q--)
        s = s - q;
    return s + 2;
}

int mocha(int n) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i = i+16)
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
            r++;
    return r;
}

int fun(int n) {
    int j=0;
    for (int k = 16; coffee(k) * mocha(k) - k <= n; k+=16) {
        j++;
        cout << "I am having so much fun with asymptotics!" << endl;
    }
    return j;
}
```

1. How would I calculate the worst case asymptotic run time of the "fun" function?
   I determined that coffee has a run time of $\Theta(n)$ and mocha has a run time of $\Theta(n^2)$
   but where do I go from there?
2. compute the return value of the function. Assume n>2 , and that n is a perfect square.
   I'm kinda just unsure where to start for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Before we analyze your algorithm for running time complexity, one point to note in the context of Asymptotic Analysis (Ref: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/asymptotic-notations)) is O(f(n)) denotes worst case (upper bound) and not Θ(f(n)).

You have already mentioned worst case asymptotic run time correctly `O(n)` for `coffee` and `O(n2)` for `mocha` where `n` is the size of the input for respective functions.

Now, looking at your multi-function algorithm, it is clear that function `fun` is the entry point with input `n`. `fun` loops through `n` (using `k`) so this code block has worst case running time complexity of `O(n)`.

```
for (int k = 16; /* coffee(k) * mocha(k) */ - k <= n; k+=16) {
    j++;
    cout << "I am having so much fun with asymptotics!" << endl;
}
```

For each value of `k`, `coffee` and `mocha` is called so they will be called `n/16` times which is `O(n)` overall. So, below is the logic to calculate worst case asymptotic run time correctly for function `fun`:

```
O(fun) = O( O(n/16) * ( O(coffee) + O(mocha) ) )
       = O( O(n/16) * ( O(n) + O(n^2) ) )
       = O( O(n^2 / 16) + O(n^3 / 16) )
       ≃ O(n^3)
```

`O( O(n2/16) + O(n3/16) )` can be simplified to `O(n3)` because `n3` is the key factor in formula `n2/16 + n3/16`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me learn more about these weird asymptotic complexity questions. Do you have any insight on the second part of the question: calculating the return value (an expression for fun(n)) given the conditions for n?

Comment: @KennyCheng, I didn't quite get your question for 2nd point. That seems like an actual implementation/logic related question. If that's the case, you will need to write a working code in your preferred language and call `fun` with various input values. I believe, you are already aware about that. If you have questions/doubts about the logic then please explain in details about the requirements for your logic/algorithm.